# Cannot delete from mongodb collection angular MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

Im trying to delete a record from my mongodb collection "setlist" in a MEAN stack application.

index.html

```
<table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Artist</th>
                    <th>Title</th>
                    <th>Key</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>&nbsp;</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="setTrack in setlist" ng-click="clicked">
                    <td><h4>{{setTrack.Artist}}</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>{{setTrack.Title}}</h4></td>
                    <td><h4>{{setTrack.Key}}</h4></td>
                    <td><button class="btn btn-success" ng-click="removeFromSL(setTrack._id)">Remove from set list</button></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

controller.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('AppCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    console.log("Hello World from controller");

    var refresh = function() {
        $http.get('/setlist').success(function(response) {
            console.log("I got the data i requested");
            $scope.setlist = response;
            $scope.setTrack = "";
        });
    };

    $scope.addToSL = function(id) {
        $http.get('/tracks/' + id).success(function(response) {
            console.log(response);
            $http.post('/setlist', response).success(function(response) {
                console.log(response);
                refresh();
            });
        });
    };

    $scope.removeFromSL = function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        $http.delete('/setlist/' + id).success(function(response) {
            refresh();
        });
    };}]);
```

server.js

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('tracks', ['tracks']);
var db1 = mongojs('setlist', ['setlist']);
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(express.static(__dirname = '\public'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/setlist', function (req, res) {
    console.log("I recieved a get request");

    db1.setlist.find(function (err, docs) {
        console.log(docs);
        res.json(docs);
    });
});

app.delete('/setlist/:id', function (req, res) {
    var id = req.params.id;
    console.log(id);
    db1.setlist.remove({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}, function(err, doc) {
        res.json(doc);
    });
});

app.listen(3000);
console.log("Server running on port 3000");
```

When i click the remove from set list button, the controller and server, fire the correct functions, because the record id is printed to the console and to the servers terminal, but the record isnt deleted from the collection.

Comment: add `if (err) { res.status(500).json(err)}` into you `remove` callback function, and use your browser's dev tool to check if there is an error returned.

Comment: No it doesnt return any errors to the console.

Comment: You sure that {_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)} has valid records in DB... try to use find to see if it's actually will find results. Im thinking transformation changes id so it's becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible issues here.

First and most likely your remove query `{_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)}` dont match any document in DB.

Second you have some error during remove stage.

So i suggest following. Check if remove query actually have documents to remove by doing like this `find({_id: mongojs.ObjectId(id)})`. If documents will be found then try print `err` and see what you have there.

Docs https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.remove/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Your first suggestion was correct. I was adding items to this collection from another collection based on the id of the record, this added all the fields correctly except the id, which was inserted as 57c1973dedf6f00b874f6611 instead of ObjectId("57c1973dedf6f00b874f6611") so when i tried to find a record using the id, it couldnt find it because the format of the field was incorrect.

Thank you. Problem solved :)